# Resharper live templates in sql files

Tags: sql, visual-studio, resharper

I created live template for creation of a stored procedure and I set availability in *.sql files. But when I'm in SQL file I don't have possibility to use live template by typing live template shortcut. I know that I have to change some setting in Visual Studio or in Resharper but I didn't find anything. Do you have any idea about that? I'm using VS 2013 and Resharper 8. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ReSharper's Live Templates only work in file formats that ReSharper supports, since Live Templates rely on other ReSharper features that need to understand languages, such as auto-formatting, name shortening and auto-imports and availability in scope. Also, Live Templates are inserted by selecting the item from ReSharper's code completion windows - if there's no code completion, there can't be any Live Templates.

Since ReSharper doesn't know about .sql files, you don't get Live Templates.

Comment: davidmdem provided an answer that works quite well.  (I suppose someone could quibble about whether it is "live" or not.)

Answer (score 5):

Custom live templates should be able to work in .sql files.

You don't mention how you set your live template up, but here is how I acheived this with Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper 8.2.

The example should allow you to type `sf + TAB` and get a `select * from $TABLE$` template inside of a .sql file.

1. Go to ReSharper's Template Explorer via RESHARPER -> Templates Explorer...
2. Make sure you are on the "Live Templates" tab (the 1st one) of the Templates Explorer.
3. Under "Scopes" on the left side make sure "Global" is selected.
4. Click the new icon to bring up the template editor.
5. Add your template shortcut keys `sf`.
6. Add your template `SELECT * FROM $TABLE$`.
7. On the right side of the template editor window, select the link next to "Availability".
8. In the "Select Scopes" window that comes up, uncheck "Everywhere" and expand "In files matching".
9. Use the File mask `*.sql`
10. OK out and save your template.

The `sf` template should now be available in .sql files.

If you've followed these steps and it's still not working, you may have keyboard shortcut conflicts with another plugin.  Consider reinstalling or repairing ReSharper or resetting the keyboard shortcuts via the RESHARPER -> Options -> Keybaord & Menus screen.